# Maps API - Find Location Based On Latitude and Longitude on Return Zero Result

Tags: google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

I want to find Location Based on Lat and Long  Via Maps API But in some Points It Returns `Zero Result` . For example a point in Persian Gulf . in such case i want to find out  this point belongs to Persian Gulf (instead of Zero Result). what is the best solution for implementing this ?

---

for example this [Link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=26.29834,52.651119&sensor=false) returns `ZERO_RESULTS` but when i search this point in google maps it understand this point belongs to Persian gulf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you get on google-maps is the response of a places-[TextSearch](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#TextSearchRequests).

So when the geocoding doesn't return any result, send an additional request to the places-service to get some informations about the coordinate.